# Lock-Free Queue with boost::atomic - Am I doing this right?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, atomic, lock-free

**Short version:**

I'm trying to replace std::atomic from C++11 used in a lock-free, single producer, single consumer queue implementation from [here](http://drdobbs.com/parallel/210604448). How do I replace this with [`boost::atomic`](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/)?

**Long version:**

I'm trying to get a better performance out of our app with worker threads. Each thread has its own task queue. We have to synchronize using lock before dequeue/enqueue each task.

Then I found Herb Sutter's article on lock-free queue. It seems like an ideal replacement. But the code uses `std::atomic` from C++11, which I couldn't introduce to the project at this time.

More googling led to some examples, such as [this one for Linux (echelon's)](http://www.soa-world.de/echelon/2011/02/a-simple-lock-free-queue-in-c.html), and [this one for Windows (TINESWARE's)](http://tinesware.blogspot.com/2009/07/simple-lockfree-queue-c-windows.html). Both use platform's specific constructs such as WinAPI's `InterlockedExchangePointer`, and GCC's `__sync_lock_test_and_set`.

I only need to support Windows & Linux so maybe I can get away with some `#ifdef`s. But I thought it might be nicer to use what `boost::atomic` provides. Boost Atomic is not part of official Boost library yet. So I downloaded the source from http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/ and use the include files with my project.

This is what I get so far:

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/atomic.hpp>

template <typename T>
class LockFreeQueue
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        Node(T val) : value(val), next(NULL) { }
        T value;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* first; // for producer only
    boost::atomic<Node*> divider;  // shared
    boost::atomic<Node*> last; // shared

public:
    LockFreeQueue()
    {
        first = new Node(T());
        divider = first;
        last= first;
    }

    ~LockFreeQueue()
    {
        while(first != NULL) // release the list
        {
            Node* tmp = first;
            first = tmp->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
    }

    void Produce(const T& t)
    {
        last.load()->next = new Node(t); // add the new item
        last = last.load()->next;
        while(first != divider) // trim unused nodes
        {
            Node* tmp = first;
            first = first->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
    }

    bool Consume(T& result)
    {
        if(divider != last) // if queue is nonempty
        {
            result = divider.load()->next->value; // C: copy it back
            divider = divider.load()->next;
            return true;  // and report success
        }
        return false;  // else report empty
    }
};
```

Some modifications to note:

```
boost::atomic<Node*> divider;  // shared
boost::atomic<Node*> last; // shared
```

and

```
    last.load()->next = new Node(t); // add the new item
    last = last.load()->next;
```

and

```
        result = divider.load()->next->value; // C: copy it back
        divider = divider.load()->next;
```

Am I applying the load() (and the implicit store()) from boost::atomic correctly right here? Can we say this is equivalent to Sutter's original C++11 lock-free queue?

PS. I studied many of the threads on SO, but none seems to provide an example for boost::atomic & lock-free queue.

Comment: Before you start poking around the lock-free hornet's nest, consider giving larger payloads to your worker threads so that the time spent on mutex contention becomes less significant. For example, if you are processing a stream of data, gather the data into large chunks before passing it on to a worker thread.

Comment: FWIF, please note, that Lockfree library was accepted to Boost: http://lists.boost.org/boost-announce/2011/08/0331.php http://tim.klingt.org/boost_lockfree/

Comment: @EmileCormier I'll work on this, thx.

Comment: @m3rLinEz Did you used your code with success?

Comment: As Igor R mentioned, the lockfree queue is already available in boost. You can use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Intel Thread Building Blocks'](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) `atomic<T>`? Cross platform and free.

Also...

**Single producer/single consumer** makes your problem much easier because your linearization point can be a single operator.  It becomes easier still if you are prepared to accept a bounded queue.

A **bounded queue** offers advantages for cache performance because you can reserve a cache aligned memory block to maximize your hits, e.g.:

```
#include <vector>
#include "tbb/atomic.h"
#include "tbb/cache_aligned_allocator.h"    

template< typename T >
class SingleProdcuerSingleConsumerBoundedQueue { 
    typedef vector<T, cache_aligned_allocator<T> > queue_type;

public:
    BoundedQueue(int capacity):
        queue(queue_type()) {
        head = 0;
        tail = 0;
        queue.reserve(capacity);
    }

    size_t capacity() {
        return queue.capacity();
    }

    bool try_pop(T& result) {
        if(tail - head == 0)
            return false;
        else {
            result = queue[head % queue.capacity()];
            head.fetch_and_increment(); //linearization point
            return(true);
        }
    }

    bool try_push(const T& source) {
        if(tail - head == queue.capacity()) 
            return(false);
        else {
            queue[tail %  queue.capacity()] = source;
            tail.fetch_and_increment(); //linearization point
            return(true);
        }
    }

    ~BoundedQueue() {}

private:
    queue_type queue;
    atomic<int> head;
    atomic<int> tail;
};
```

Comment: indeed it does and the concurrent_bounded_queue Template Class
would be a lovely drop in solution but I think OP was interested in an optimized solution therefore I still propose the above

Comment: wouldn't tail %  queue.capacity() produce a negative result after tail rolls over? evan if you switched to an unsigned int wouldn't capacity have to be a divisor of MAX_INT ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [boost.atomic ringbuffer example](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/doc/atomic/usage_examples.html#boost_atomic.usage_examples.example_ringbuffer) from the documentation:

```
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>

template <typename T, size_t Size>
class ringbuffer
{
public:
    ringbuffer() : head_(0), tail_(0) {}

    bool push(const T & value)
    {
        size_t head = head_.load(boost::memory_order_relaxed);
        size_t next_head = next(head);
        if (next_head == tail_.load(boost::memory_order_acquire))
            return false;
        ring_[head] = value;
        head_.store(next_head, boost::memory_order_release);
        return true;
    }

    bool pop(T & value)
    {
        size_t tail = tail_.load(boost::memory_order_relaxed);
        if (tail == head_.load(boost::memory_order_acquire))
            return false;
        value = ring_[tail];
        tail_.store(next(tail), boost::memory_order_release);
        return true;
    }

private:
    size_t next(size_t current)
    {
        return (current + 1) % Size;
    }

    T ring_[Size];
    boost::atomic<size_t> head_, tail_;
};

// How to use    
int main()
{
    ringbuffer<int, 32> r;

    // try to insert an element
    if (r.push(42)) { /* succeeded */ }
    else { /* buffer full */ }

    // try to retrieve an element
    int value;
    if (r.pop(value)) { /* succeeded */ }
    else { /* buffer empty */ }
}
```

The code's only limitation is that the buffer length has to be known at compile time (or at construction time, if you replace the array by a `std::vector<T>`). To allow the buffer to grow and shrink is not trivial, as far as I understand.